# Grid with [class*='col-']:last-of-type

Tags: css

i want to user [class*='col-']:last-of-type for my grid to remove margins.

```
<div class="col-1-3"></div>
<div class="col-2-3"></div>
```

css:

```
[class*='col-'] {margin-right: 10px}
[class*='col-']:last-of-type {margin:0}
```

But on the last element (in this case col-2-3) does not applied the :last-of-type

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Please provide a fiddle demonstrating the behavior you're experiencing.

Comment: here a example https://jsfiddle.net/susy19ee/

Answer (score 0):

:last-of-type cannot find classes/id's, unfortunately. It can only find the HTML element.

Try the ~ selector instead like:

`div ~ [class*='col-'] {margin:0}`

https://jsfiddle.net/susy19ee/1/

Comment: It does not work with more then 2 div-elements with col- classes like here: https://jsfiddle.net/susy19ee/2/